# MongoDb find method with parameters return empty results

Tags: excel, mongodb

I imported an excel file in my mongodb and the find() method works perfectly. But when I search using key/value in the find method, I get empty reults. I have imported by removing the headers from excel because it had duplicates and so the column names I stored it in a seperate file.

Comment: Would help if you post a snippet data from the excel file, and the resulting data in MongoDB. You may also want to have a look at [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), which is able to import csv data format. Thanks

Comment: Please post an example of data imported into mongo database along with search criteria to fetch records

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this. I am facing similar issue